# Where does outlining get stored in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have started to use outlining in C# as follows:

```
Edit > Outlining > Hide Selection
```

Does the outlining and the state of each hidden area get stored some place and what 
happens if so then will all this information get lost if I upgrade Visual Studion or move my code 
into another VS2010 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS2010 and VS2012, outlining is stored in the solution's `.suo` file. Off the top of my head, some things stored in the `.suo` file:

- The files that are open in VS
- Where the files are displayed (tab group, tab order)
- Outlining information

The `.suo` file does not store anything that affects building the solution. It can be deleted with no ill effects (other than losing the display information). In general, this file isn't included in source control. TFS does not add this file automatically. I always make sure *.suo is in my .hgingore file (Mercurial).

To answer the specific questions asked: Yes, if you move your code into another solution, this information is lost (i.e. does not automatically move with it). Upgrading Visual Studio also loses this information. It really isn't anything to worry about, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's stored in the `*.suo` or `*.csproj.user` files. These are binary files that store per-solution and per-project metadata on a per-developer (or rather, per-machine) basis, which is why they're excluded from source control by default. They include settings on VS window layout and the state of collapsed/expanded regions, and more.

Because `*.suo` files are bound to corresponding `*.sln` files it means they are not shared between VS versions. I think VS can upgrade some SUO files, but I don't know about `csproj.user` files (as `csproj` files are portable between VS versions).